# Pandas: Pivoting dataframe to one row per User (group)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, concatenation, pandas-groupby

Firstly, this is not a duplicate question, I have looked at similar questions, but the solutions are not correct for this example.

Here is a simplified example of my pandas dataframe:

```
  User Category Frequency    Visit 1 Date_Time    Visit 2 Date_Time  \

0    A    alpha         1  2020-03-01 00:00:00                    -   

1    A     beta         2  2020-04-01 00:00:00  2020-06-01 00:00:00   

2    B    alpha         3  2020-06-01 00:00:00  2020-07-01 00:00:00   

3    B     beta         1  2020-07-01 00:00:00                    -   

4    B    gamma         3  2018-10-01 00:00:00  2019-06-01 00:00:00   

5    C    gamma         1  2019-08-01 00:00:00                    -   

6    C   indigo         1  2018-09-01 00:00:00                    -   



     Visit 3 Date_Time Visit 4 Date_Time  

0                    -          -  

1                    -          - 

2  2020-08-01 00:00:00          -  

3                    -          -             

4  2020-10-01 00:00:00          - 

5                    -          -        

6                    -          -
```

I would like to transform this dataframe so that it has exactly one row per User, like below. One important thing to note is that the Visit Date_Time columns are not fixed, the code should also work if Visit 5 Date_Time existed, for example.

```
  User  alpha_Frequency alpha_Visit 1 Date_Time alpha_Visit 2 Date_Time  \

0    A                1     2020-03-01 00:00:00                       -   

1    B                3     2020-06-01 00:00:00     2020-07-01 00:00:00   

2    C                0                       -                       -   



  alpha_Visit 3 Date_Time alpha_Visit 4 Date_Time  beta_Frequency  \

0                       -                       -               2   

1     2020-08-01 00:00:00                       -               1   

2                       -                       -               0   



  beta_Visit 1 Date_Time beta_Visit 2 Date_Time beta_Visit 3 Date_Time  \

0    2020-04-01 00:00:00    2020-06-01 00:00:00                      -   

1    2020-07-01 00:00:00                      -                      -   

2                      -                      -                      -   



            ...            gamma_Frequency  gamma_Visit 1 Date_Time  \

0           ...                          0                        -   

1           ...                          3      2018-10-01 00:00:00   

2           ...                          1      2019-08-01 00:00:00   



  gamma_Visit 2 Date_Time gamma_Visit 3 Date_Time gamma_Visit 4 Date_Time  \

0                       -                       -                       -   

1     2019-06-01 00:00:00     2020-10-01 00:00:00                       -   

2                       -                       -                       -   



  indigo_Frequency  indigo_Visit 1 Date_Time indigo_Visit 2 Date_Time  \

0                0                         -                        -   

1                0                         -                        -   

2                1       2018-09-01 00:00:00                        -   



  indigo_Visit 3 Date_Time indigo_Visit 4 Date_Time  

0                        -                        -  

1                        -                        -  

2                        -                        -
```

Essentially, it is concatenating the Category column with the Frequency and Visit Date_Time columns, then pivoting.

The code below I have tried, but it does not quite work.

```
df.pivot_table(index='User', 
                     columns=df.groupby('Category').cumcount(),
                     aggfunc='first').sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a means to create the sample dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should solve your problem

```
import pandas as pd

# Example df
data = {'user': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
        'category':['a','b', 'a', 'b', 'g', 'g', 'i'],
        'freq': [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
        'visit_1_date': ['2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result = df.pivot(index='user', columns='category')
print(result.head())

# OUTPUT
         freq                visit_1_date                                    
category    a    b    g    i            a           b           g           i
user                                                                         
A         1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN   2019-10-01  2019-10-01         NaN         NaN
B         3.0  1.0  3.0  NaN   2019-10-01  2019-10-01  2019-10-01         NaN
C         NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0          NaN         NaN  2019-10-01  2019-10-01
```

If you try the same code but with a dataset with more columns like **visit_2_date, ...** you will get the expanded results.

```
data = {'user': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
        'category':['a','b', 'a', 'b', 'g', 'g', 'i'],
        'freq': [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
        'visit_1_date': ['2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01'],
        'visit_2_date': ['2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result = df.pivot(index='user', columns='category')
print(result.head())

# OUTPUT
         freq                 ... visit_2_date                                    
category    a    b    g    i  ...            a           b           g           i
user                          ...                                                 
A         1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  ...   2019-10-01  2019-10-01         NaN         NaN
B         3.0  1.0  3.0  NaN  ...   2019-10-01  2019-10-01  2019-10-01         NaN
C         NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  ...          NaN         NaN  2019-10-01  2019-10-01
```

Basically, when we pivot using **user** as index-parameter we force to return one-row per user. If we setting **category** as columns-parameter without specifying the values-parameter, the function will use remaining columns as values.

Check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for further information